# RC4 in C and Python do not give the same result

Tags: python, c

I have been using RC4 in C for a long time (simple function that I've found in the internet), recently, I wanted to do string encryption in python and move it to C program, so I found the same function in python, but it does not give the same result as C function
here are both functions :

C :

```
LPBYTE RC4(LPBYTE lpBuf, LPBYTE lpKey, DWORD dwBufLen, DWORD dwKeyLen){
    INT a, b = 0, s[256];
    BYTE swap;
    DWORD dwCount;
    for(a = 0; a < 256; a++){
        s[a] = a;
    }
    for(a = 0; a < 256; a++){
        b = (b + s[a] + lpKey[a % dwKeyLen]) % 256;
        swap = s[a];
        s[a] = s[b];
        s[b] = swap;
    }

    a = b = 0

    for(dwCount = 0; dwCount < dwBufLen; dwCount++){
        a = (a + 1) % 256;
        b = (b + s[a]) % 256;
        swap = s[a];
        s[a] = s[b];
        s[b] = swap;
        lpBuf[dwCount] ^= s[(s[a] + s[b]) % 256];
    }
    return lpBuf;
}
```

Python :

```
def rc4(data , key):
    S = list(range(256))
    b = 0
    out = []

    #KSA Phase
    for a in range(256):
        b = (b + S[a] + ord( key[a % len(key)] )) % 256
        S[a] , S[b] = S[b] , S[a]

    #PRGA Phase
    a = b = 0
    for dwCount in data:
        a = ( a + 1 ) % 256
        b = ( b + S[a] ) % 256
        S[a] , S[b] = S[b] , S[a]
        out.append(chr(ord(dwCount) ^ S[(S[a] + S[b]) % 256]))

    return ''.join(out)
```

So, why the encrypted string with these two functions is not the same ?

Comment: Hey, we will need the expected outputs from two inputs.  Even then, *what is wrong with my code* kinds of questions tend not to be specific enough to be a good fit for this website.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I said in my question that the encrypted string with these two functions is not the same

Comment: In order to compare both versions, it would also be helpful if corresponding variables had the same names.

Answer (score 1):

The snippets are not equivalent. In the beginning of PRGA phase, python code sets `b` to 0. The C code does not reinitialize the corresponding variable, and uses a leftover from KSA phase. One of the snippets must be wrong. I do not know RC4 to tell which one.

Comment: I didn't see that, I corrected it in the C version, the result, it gives different result but not the same as python :(

Comment: @NadjibDz You have not corrected this. There is no equivalent to the Python version's line `a = b = 0` in the C version.